# how to deform or animate a object like this

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

how should I approach it if I want to apply a cover on a phone, I have used curves before but I don't know if it's possible to make it work like this, Rigging the cover might work but I feel like the object wouldn't be curved with that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can give a *Curve* modifier to your plastic film and move the curve:

[image]

Diagonally, just rotate the curve on Z:

[image]

[image]

Chris' hint: you can even add hooks to your bezier curves points and animate that hooks so even the curve's shape can be animated as well simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: You don't by any chance have a nice snappy way to do this on a diagonal. as in the ref? I still find this a right-royal pain.. :)

Comment: if you just rotate the curve it will go diagonally, is it what you mean?

Comment: I've tried every which way. Goes haywire. Can you share the working diagonal version on pasteall or somesuch, so I can have a look at the object axes, etc, when convenient for you? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check and tell me if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to do exactly the same, but in Y. (rotate all by 90 in Z, apply rotation, switch Y for X in modifier).  But that throws the relationship with the curve's tilt. The tilt then has to be set to 90 for it to work. (That will be the result of a cross-product, I guess) Lesson for me: always set up in Object/Curve X,

Comment: @moonboots Idk why but when I use a bezier curve my object gets deformed, is there anything you did to you object ??

Comment: make sure that you've applied the scale of your curve and also switch it to Edit mode, select all and right click > Set Curve Radius, type 1 and Enter. If it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: I had already done all that but I changed its tilt to 90 and it worked, I still don't know why I had to turn on tilt but it somehow worked